# getting count from multiple tables on the basis of gender and scored percentages

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use 3 tables

```
1. tbl_school_info 
school_id   school_name
1           St. Joseph
2           White Cross

2. tbl_student_info
student_id      school_id       student_name    student_gender
1                   1           maria liejal        F
2                   1           eerika carthy       F
3                   1           heron               M
4                   2           Glenn hui           M
5                   2           joseph              M
6                   2           christii            F
7                   2           hina moggy          F

3. tbl_student_marks 
marks_id        school_id       student_id          scored_percentage
1                   1               1                       78
2                   1               2                       79
3                   1               3                       20
4                   2               4                       65
5                   2               5                       78
6                   2               6                       84
7                   2               7                       83
```

The result I need is the male, female and total student count in each school, male female passed student count and highest percentage scored male female students. The result will be like this ::

```
school_name || male_stud_cnt || female_stud_cnt || passed_male_cnt || passed_female_cnt || top_percentage_male ||top_percentage_female
St. Joseph          1               2                   0                   2                       20                  79
White Cross         2               2                   2                   2                       78                  84
```

The students whose score is below 35% has failed in the exam. How can I write query to get this result ? Is it possible to get such result using SQL query in MS SQL Server? I am unable to get the counts, how can I write such query ?

Comment: If this is school homework, can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using condtional aggregation with case when expression

```
with cte as
(
select school_name,a.student_id,student_gender,scored_percentage from
tbl_student_marks a inner join tbl_student_info b
on a.student_id=b.student_id
inner join tbl_school_info c on a.school_id=b.school_id
)
select school_name, 
       count(case when student_gender='M' then student_id end) as male_stud_cnt,
       count(case when student_gender='F' then student_id end) as female_stud_cnt,
       count(case when student_gender='M' and scored_percentage>35 then student_id end) as passed_male_cnt,
       count(case when student_gender='F' and scored_percentage>35 then student_id end) as passed_female_cnt,
       max(case when student_gender='M' then scored_percentage end) as top_percentage_male,
       max(case when student_gender='F' then scored_percentage end) as top_percentage_female
from cte 
group by school_name
```